# Spark dataframe slice

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I've a table with (millions of) entries along the lines of the following example read into a Spark dataframe (`sdf`):

| Id | C1 | C2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| xx1 | c118 | c219 |
| xx1 | c113 | c218 |
| xx1 | c118 | c214 |
| acb | c121 | c201 |
| e3d | c181 | c221 |
| e3d | c132 | c252 |
| abq | c141 | c290 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| vy1 | c13023 | C23021 |

I'd like to get a smaller subset of these *Id's* for further processing. I identify the unique set of *Id's* in the table using `sdf_id = sdf.select("Id").dropDuplicates()`.

What is the efficient way from here to filter data (*C1*, *C2*) related to, let's say, 100 randomly selected *Id's*?

Comment: Do you need **full data per ID** for a subset of IDs? or any subset of records is fine?

Comment: Hello @pltc, I need full data per ID for a subset of IDs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to achieve what you want.

###### My sample data

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame([
    (1, 'a'),
    (1, 'b'),
    (1, 'c'),
    (2, 'd'),
    (2, 'e'),
    (3, 'f'),
], ['id', 'col'])
```

###### The initial step is getting the sample IDs that you wanted

```py
ids = df.select('id').distinct().sample(0.2) # 2 is 20%, you can adjust this

+---+
| id|
+---+
|  1|
+---+
```

###### Approach #1: using inner join

Since you have two dataframes, you can just perform a single inner join to get all records from `df` for each id in `ids`. Note that `F.broadcast` is to boost up the performance because `ids` suppose to be small enough. Feel free to take it away if you want to. Performance-wise, this approach is preferred.

```py
df.join(F.broadcast(ids), on=['id'], how='inner').show()

+---+---+
| id|col|
+---+---+
|  1|  a|
|  1|  b|
|  1|  c|
+---+---+
```

###### Approach #2: using `isin`

You can't simply get the list of IDs via `ids.collect()`, because that would return a list of `Row`, you have to loop through it to get the exact column that you want (`id` in this case).

```py
df.where(F.col('id').isin([r['id'] for r in ids.collect()])).show()

+---+---+
| id|col|
+---+---+
|  1|  a|
|  1|  b|
|  1|  c|
+---+---+
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have the list of unique `ids` , you can further sample it to your desired fraction and filter based on that

There are other ways you can sample random ids , which can be found [here](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-sampling-example/)

#### Sampling

```
### Assuming the DF is 1 mil records , 100 records would be 0.01%

sdf_id = sdf.select("Id").dropDuplicates().sample(0.01).collect()
```

#### Filter

```
sdf_filtered = sdf.filter(F.col('Id').isin(sdf_id))
```

Comment: Thanks Vaebhav. I'm able to successfully sample but get the following error with filtering step. 

``` An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.sql.functions.lit.
: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unsupported literal type class java.util.ArrayList```

Do you have any suggestions to fix?